# Kafka does not start on port 9092 using docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I followed this [link](https://www.conduktor.io/kafka/how-to-start-kafka-using-docker/) to start Kafka using docker. In my OS, docker and docker-compose were preinstalled.

I cloned the repo mentioned on that website and navigated to that directory. Then, I opened the terminal in that directory and executed this command: `sudo docker-compose -f zk-single-kafka-single.yml up -d` without any error. Then, to verify whether the containers are running, I entered `sudo docker ps`; the output I got on the terminal is shown in the image below.
[image]

But when I hit localhost:9092 on my browser, no pages load. But on my terminal, it is showing that Kafka is running.

So what might be the issue here?

Comment: can you share your k-single-kafka-single.yml file ?

Comment: Hi. Can you point to any documentation that says that a browser can be used to reach Kafka on that port? Perhaps you want to also run a Kafka UI tool like CMAK or AKHQ or RedPanda Console or use Conduktor's own tooling? And those would load in the browser on a _different port_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It won't display any pages because Kafka uses a binary protocol for communication rather than a web-based interface. `Port:9092` is used for communication between Kafka clients and Kafka broker.
- To interact with Kafka, you have to use Kafka client library or command-line tools.